# Actor Gateway for Kaa Server - Java based

Tags: java, kaa

I am using KAA iOT server to connect my hardware with cloud. I have implemeted MQTT protocol in hardware and need to implement Actor Gateway or some other solution to enable communication between hardware and cloud. I am unable to find any guide on how to implement actor gateway. Any help please.

Answer (score 1):

Currently KAA only support HTTP/HTTPS, it does not support MQTT protocol. Actor gateway(Like Raspberry Pi, Cloudgate etc) will have the Kaa's SDK which will be bundled with application running on Actor gateway. The application running on Actor gateway should MQTT implementation. Your device will talk to Actor gateway with MQTT protocol. You have to design your system in that fashion.

Below diagram will show you the Actor Gateway approach:

[image]